# How to show only time picker in date range picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, daterangepicker

I am using daterange picker i want show only timepicker but its not working following is the link which is i am using for reference.

```js
$(function() {
    $('#single_cal4').daterangepicker({
  singleDatePicker: true,
        datePicker: false,
        timePicker: true,
 
    });
})
```

http://www.daterangepicker.com/

Comment: `datePicker: false` is simply not a part of the plug-in. If any use, I use http://keith-wood.name/timeentry.html when I need just a time picker.

Comment: @Darren Sweeney thankyou. But whenever I am trying to include another time picker in it is is throwing error.

Comment: Pretty broad statement, can you clarify what you mean throwing error? What error?

Answer (score 28):

```
$('#duration').daterangepicker({
            timePicker: true,
            timePicker24Hour: true,
            timePickerIncrement: 1,
            timePickerSeconds: true,
            locale: {
                format: 'HH:mm:ss'
            }
        }).on('show.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {
            picker.container.find(".calendar-table").hide();
        });
```

Comment: As simple as that... I wish I found this earlier... KUDOS!

Answer (score 12):

**If you want a range of time :**

```
$(function() {
   $('#single_cal4').daterangepicker({
            timePicker : true,
            timePicker24Hour : true,
            timePickerIncrement : 1,
            timePickerSeconds : true,
            locale : {
                format : 'HH:mm:ss'
            }
        }).on('show.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
            picker.container.find(".calendar-table").hide();
   });
})
```

**If you want single time picker:**

```
$(function() {
   $('#single_cal4').daterangepicker({
            timePicker : true,
            singleDatePicker:true,
            timePicker24Hour : true,
            timePickerIncrement : 1,
            timePickerSeconds : true,
            locale : {
                format : 'HH:mm:ss'
            }
        }).on('show.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
            picker.container.find(".calendar-table").hide();
   });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Those above does not work for me. But this works

`$(function() {
   $('#single_cal4').daterangepicker({
            timePicker : true,
            singleDatePicker:true,
            timePicker24Hour : true,
            timePickerIncrement : 1,
            timePickerSeconds : true,
            locale : {
                format : 'HH:mm:ss'
            }
        }).on('show.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
            picker.container.find(".calendar-date").hide();
        }).on('showCalendar.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker){
           picker.container.find('.calendar-date').remove();
        });
})`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular 2+, you can use this:

https://github.com/evansmwendwa/ng2-daterangepicker

and then hide the calendar with this:

```
::ng-deep .calendar-table {
  display: none;
}
```